# Is there optional chaining in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to omit checks for null in chained statements like

```
if($a && $a->$b && $a->$b->$c){
  $d = $a->$b->$c;
}
```

and use optional chaining instead.

Is this possible or implemented in PHP?

Comment: No, that is not implemented.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In PHP versions less than 8, optional chaining isn't supported. You can emulate it *for properties* by using the [error control operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) (`@`) which will suppress any errors that would normally occur from the assignment. For example:

```
$b = 'b';
$c = 'c';
$e = 'e';
$a = (object)['b' => (object)['e' => 2]];
@$d = $a->$b->$c;
var_dump($d);
@$d = $a->$b->$e;
var_dump($d);
```

Output:

```
NULL
int(2)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jYAj9)

A better solution is to use the null coalescing operator as described in @FouedMOUSSI answer.

As of PHP8 (released 2020-11-26) optional chaining is supported via the [nullsafe operator](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#nullsafe-operator) (see @Paul answer or the posted duplicate).

Answer (score 39):

Not until PHP 8.0.

This has been voted on and passed in the [Nullsafe operator RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator).

The syntax will be `?->`.

So the statement:

```
if ($a && $a->$b && $a->$b->$c) {
  $d = $a->$b->$c;
}
```

Could be rewritten to:

```
$d = $a?->$b?->$c;  // If you are happy to assign null to $d upon failure
```

Or:

```
if ($a?->$b?->$c) {
  $d = $a->$b->$c; // If you want to keep it exactly per the previous statement
}
```

The Nullsafe operator works for both properties and methods.

Comment: Coming from Swift, I instantly typed ?-> thinking it would work, but before giving it a try I looked this up and ended here!

Answer (score 34):

According to this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/whats-new-in-php-7-and-php-7-new-features)
"The null coalescing operator ( introduced in PHP 7) is represented like this **??** used to check if the value is set or null, or in other words, if the value exists and not null, then it returns the first operand, otherwise, it returns the second operand."

So you can easily do

```
$d = $a->$b->$c ?? 'DEFAULT' ;
```

EDIT: This only works for properties, not methods (as pointed out by  "hackel" in the comments below)

Comment: Didn't know this also works for chaining. Best solution.

Comment: did you verified this information yourself?
it seems that it doesn't work at all 
`class Something {
    public function getSomething() { return null; }
}

$something = new Something();
var_dump($something->getSomething()->getSomethingElse() ?? 'default');
`

 produces `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSomethingElse() on null`

Comment: According to the docs, the null coalescing operator is just syntantic sugar: `exprA ?? exprB` is equivalent to `isset(exprA) ? exprA : exprB`. isset supports something like optional chaining but just for arrays. `$empty = []; isset($empty['a']['b']); // false, no exception`

Comment: @Oliboy50 It only works for properties, not methods.  e.g.
`$a = new class () {
    public $b;
};
$d = $a->b->c ?? 'DEFAULT';`

Comment: Thank you @hackel I edited and removed my downvote then :)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @Paul the nullsafe is available in PHP 8.
After reading this question today I just realized PHP 8 was released yesterday (2020-11-26) with nullsafe operators available :)

So yes it is available in PHP now and I can't wait to use it.

https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php